# Facing the time bomb in computers?

Tags: time, year2038

It is about the representation of time by using an `int` to store the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

**When will programs that use this representation face a time bomb? How should you proceed when that happens?**

Comment: Please share code as well what all you have done?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: i hope by system.currentmilliseconds i can able to get the int, But i am unable to understand the time bomb (q?)

Comment: I formatted and reworded your question. Changed tags.

Answer (score 1):

We are 2015 today. The number of seconds approximately since 1/1/1970 is

```
(2015 - 1970) * 365,25 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 1.420.092.000
```

That is the number of seconds in 45 years.

An `unsigned int` (32 bit) can store the value

```
4.294.967.295
```

which leaves us with

```
2.874.875.295 seconds ~ 90 years to go from now on
```

We still got some time to go.

In case a `signed int` is used, refer to this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) (Thank you PM for the comment).

The `signed int` can store

```
2.147.483.647
```

which leaves us with

```
727.391.647 ~ 23 years to go from now on, i.e. 2038.
```

> **And thus the name of this problem: the Year 2038 problem**

That is it can arise before our retirement.

For whatever you are concerned about, please refer to [this link on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=year2038).